# Character classes and negation with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering if there's any way with Regex to accept the characters associated with a given character set WHILE negating a couple of other characters?

For instance, consider the case where I want to accept all the characters, digits and underscores (`\w`) except the letter `e`, and the digit `1`. Is there a quick way to accomplish that? Ideally, I'd love something akin to `^[\w^e1]$`, although I know this specific one won't work.

Comment: I'm fairly certain your question doesn't have an answer (hope i'm wrong though), but it's definitely a real question.  Not sure why someone would down vote this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this via [character class subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction):

> [base_group - [excluded_group]]

Using this format, the pattern `^[\w-[e1]]$` can be used to match all alphanumeric characters excluding the letter `e` and number `1`.

```
string[] inputs = 
{
    "a", "b", "c", "_", "2", "3",
    " ", "1", "e"   // false cases
};
string pattern = @"^[\w-[e1]]$";
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern), input);
}
```

Comment: Just a disclaimer for this: Not supported in the majority of RegEx flavors. Fine while you're using .NET, just something to bear in mind if you're ever using the Regular Expression elsewhere.

Comment: @JasonLarke that's true. For reference, the [regex flavor comparison chart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) shows which flavors support this feature (very limited support).

Comment: Awesome. I have one more question, though. When trying to replace *\w* by *[a-z]* (or any other character set), it won't match anything. Any specific reason? Ah, NVM. The link you provided answered the question. I wonder why didn't they follow the more natural variant I above imagined, though.

Comment: @devouredelysium that's not possible. Character classes alter the behavior of certain regex metacharacters. Outside of a character class, a `.` matches any char, but inside it matches a literal dot or period. The same applies to quantifiers. The [`Regex.Escape` method's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) mentions the metacharacters that are typically affected.

Comment: Be sure to document what you are doing with this (if using among other developers). With such limited support, at first glance this could be mistaken for a character range (not a subtraction)!

Answer (score 0):

A more *portable* but less succinct way than Ahmad's solution would be to just define a character class that excludes `e` and `1`.

```
[a-df-zA-DF-Z02-9]
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: In the .NET flavour of regex, `\w` matches all Unicode characters in the Ll, Lu, Lt, Lo, Lm, Nd and Pc categories. That are a bit too many characters to list explicitly.